# How to use Crinsane Laravel Shopping cart in laravel 5.7?

Tags: laravel, shopping-cart, laravel-5.7

I used this package in laravel 5.5. It's an awesome package that I know. But in laravel 5.7 doesn't install. darryldecode cart is not good for me.

is there any way that I can use Crinsane Laravel Shopping cart in laravel 5.7

Comment: yeah, few days ago i also tried to use it but it doesn't support on laravel 5.7. So, i use my custom code for the cart system...

Comment: Are you getting some kind of specific problem or issue?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. I read all issues in github about "Crinsane Laravel Shopping cart" & found the update version for laravel 5.7 is
https://github.com/hardevine/LaravelShoppingcart
.
It works fine